# EntityNotFoundException when saving Objects referencing each other

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I have a class B which has a set with objects of class A.
Objects from class A can reference each other. 
So i am loading object from class B which has already one object from class A added. Now i am adding a new object from class A, which will be referenced by the first. When i try to save this, most of the time it will end in an EntityNotFoundException. I could try saving from last item to first, but this will not work if you see this example:

```
    public class A implements java.io.Serializable {

    private BigInteger id;
    private A succes;
    private A fail;

    public A(BigInteger id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setSuccess(A a) {
        this.success = a;
    }

    public void setFail(A a) {
        this.fail = a;
    }

}

public class B implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Set<A> setA = new HashSet<A>();

    public void addA(A a) {
        this.setA.add(a);
    }

    public Set<A> getSetA() {
        return this.setA;
    }

}

public class Util {

    public static void update(B b) throws JDBCException, PSQLException {
        EntityManager em = null;
        EntityTransaction tx = null;
        try {
            em = HibernateUtil.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
            tx = em.getTransaction();
            tx.begin();
            em.merge(b);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            tx.rollback();
            logger.error(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            Throwable cause = e.getCause();
            if (cause instanceof JDBCException) {
                throw (JDBCException) cause;
            }
            if (cause instanceof PSQLException) {
                throw (PSQLException) cause;
            }
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    public static BigInteger getNextID() {
        // returns next value of sequence
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    B b = ... // load from DB
    A a1 = b.getSetA.get(0);
    A a2 = new A(Util.getNextID());
    A a3 = new A(Util.getNextID());
    A a4 = new A(Util.getNextID());
    a1.setSuccess(a2);
    a2.setSuccess(a3);
    a3.setSuccess(a4);
    a4.setFail(a2);
    b.addA(a2);
    b.addA(a3);
    b.addA(a4);
    Util.update(b); // throws javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException Unable to find A with id xxx

}
```

From the XML-HBM-file of class B:

```
<set embed-xml="true" fetch="select" cascade="all-delete-orphan"
    lazy="true" mutable="true" name="A"
    optimistic-lock="true" table="A" inverse="true"
    sort="unsorted">
    <key>
        <column name="A_ID" />
    </key>
    <one-to-many
        class="A" embed-xml="true"
        not-found="exception" />
</set>
```

How should i solve this?

Edit: 
I can use

```
em.unwrap(Session.class).update("B", b);
```

But this ends in an IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance when removing an object from class A.

Comment: Does class `A` also have a reference to `B`? As you manually set the ID for each `A`, they need to be persisted before being added to `B#setA`. If you don't want to save each `A` first and only update your `B` instance, you need to use a database generated identifier for `A`, like an `IDENTITY` column or a database `SEQUENCE`

Comment: Class A has a reference to B (many-to-one). I get the IDs for A with nextVal from database, because User needs the ID to set succes and fail before writing to database. That's why i can't use IDENTITY or SEQUENCE for A (or does another way exist?). I think the problem is that Hibernate thinks the objects already exist in database because they have an ID?

Comment: Do they really need the ID or just an instance of A? `I think the problem is that Hibernate thinks the objects already exist in database because they have an ID?` -> that is correct. That is why I said: `As you manually set the ID for each A, they need to be persisted before being added to B#setA`. Either you manually persist each A, or you let the database auto generate the IDs

Comment: The users really need the ID to identify the As. A has also a name-variable, but the names are not unique. A lot of As in database have the same name and a Set<A> can have multiple As with the same name. So the only way is to persist each A and than persist B?

Comment: Yes, with the given setup, that is the way to go

Comment: Thank you very much :) can i give you the bounty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the additional information given in the comments, we found that the solution is to persist the `A` instances manually before adding them to an instance of `B`.

As the ids of `A` are manually created in the code before the instances are persisted, hibernate "thinks" that the instances should be available in the database as they have an ID which is not generated by the database. This causes the `EntityNotFoundException` when updating a `B` before all `A`s are persisted.

There are actually two different solutions:

1. Let the database generate the IDs of `A` either via an `IDENTITY` column or by using a `SEQUENCE`. With that, hibernate can cascade the persists from `B` to `A`.
2. Manually persist all `A`s before adding them to `B`. This is only necessary if the IDs are manually created.

And since the requirements in question are that the IDs are available before actually persisting each `A`, solution 2 must be used here. In fact, it is even most probably necessary, to persist each `A`, before calling either `setSuccess(a2)` and `setFail(a2)`.